# Extent report started to be broken in any browser

Tags: java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Accidentally my extent report view started to be very broken and I can not understand why. Will add a screenshot and some piece of codes here

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

@BeforeClass
  public synchronized void beforeClass(ITestContext ctx) {
    suiteName = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getName();
    ExtentTest parent = ExtentManager.getInstance(suiteName).createTest(getClass().getName());
    parentTest.set(parent);
  }

@BeforeMethod
  public void setup(Method method) throws IOException {
    //Extent report config
    ExtentTest child = parentTest.get().createNode(method.getName());
    test.set(child);
    Reporter.log("Method -" + method.getName() + " - is started.");
    Reporter.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

  }

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
  public void closeWindow(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
      test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
      Reporter.logFail("Test FAILED");
    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
      test.get().skip(result.getThrowable());
    else
      test.get().pass("Test passed");

    ExtentManager.getInstance(suiteName).flush();

    Reporter.log("Stopping tests");
  }
```

Adding the screenshot how the result looks like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AbUl.png)

Comment: Are you inserting any HTML that may break the structure?

Comment: If I am not wrong, I see only Test instance is flushed and Extent Report instance is not flushed as per above code